# How to convert flat PHP array to indexed array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
'values' => [
        'protein_question_0_typing_method' => '38'
        'protein_question_0_amount_1' => '1'
        'protein_question_0_amount_2' => '2'
        'protein_question_0_units_of_measurement' => '17'
        'protein_question_1_typing_method' => '39'
        'protein_question_1_amount_1' => '2'
        'protein_question_1_amount_2' => '2'
        'protein_question_1_units_of_measurement' => '17'
        'protein_question_2_typing_method' => '42'
        'protein_question_2_amount_1' => '2'
        'protein_question_2_amount_2' => '2'
        'protein_question_2_units_of_measurement' => '17'
        'distributionId' => '21'
    ]
```

How would I convert into a structure like this?

```
'values' => [
         0 => [
          'protein_question_typing_method' => '38',
          'protein_question_amount_1' => '1',
          'protein_question_amount_2' => '2'
         ],
         1 => [
          'protein_question_typing_method' => '42',
          'protein_question_amount_1' => '1',
          'protein_question_amount_2' => '2'
         ],
         ...

        'distributionId' => '21'
    ]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
       $params = \Yii::$app->request->post();

        $length = count($params['values']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

            if(!empty($params['values']['protein_question_' . $i . '_typing_method'])) {
                echo $params['values']['protein_question_' . $i . '_typing_method'] . "<br /><hr />";
            }

        }
```

**The above code just prints the data, the reason I need it in the chunked format is because each chunk will be saved as a new model record in the DB.**

So basically just need to convert it to an index array, anyone know the easiest way to do this as looping over the first array would be complicated?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried in order to do this yourself?

Comment: This looks like Advanced custom fields in wordpress is this what you are using?

Comment: @Epodax See update.

Comment: @BenLonsdale No this is not WordPress, it's a custom Yii2 project

Comment: And what does your attempted code do? What is going wrong with the code you've tried? Are there any errors? If so, please include them.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Changing the source might be a better idea than manipulating the result.

Comment: "looping over the first array would be complicated"? No, it's not. You go over the values and check the digit after protein_question.The use that as the key for your output array.

Comment: @Epodax see me update.

Comment: @jeroen It's an API call, I don't have control over the source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do

```
$input = [
'values' => [
    'protein_question_0_typing_method' => '38',
        'protein_question_0_amount_1' => '1',
        'protein_question_0_amount_2' => '2',
        'protein_question_0_units_of_measurement' => '17',
        'protein_question_1_typing_method' => '39',
        'protein_question_1_amount_1' => '2',
        'protein_question_1_amount_2' => '2',
        'protein_question_1_units_of_measurement' => '17',
        'protein_question_2_typing_method' => '42',
        'protein_question_2_amount_1' => '2',
        'protein_question_2_amount_2' => '2',
        'protein_question_2_units_of_measurement' => '17',
        'distributionId' => '21'
    ]
];

$output = [];
foreach ($input["values"] as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('#^protein_question_(\d+)_(.+)$#', $key, $match)) {
        $output[$match[1]]['protein_question_' . $match[2]] = $value;
    } else {
        $output[$key] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($output);
```

This will iterate over all the keys in the array and match if the start with protein_question, followed by a number, followed by some text. If so, the number is used as the index in the output to hold the key minus the number along with the value. If it doesnt match, the key and value are put as is.

Will give

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["protein_question_typing_method"]=>
    string(2) "38"
    ["protein_question_amount_1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["protein_question_amount_2"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["protein_question_units_of_measurement"]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["protein_question_typing_method"]=>
    string(2) "39"
    ["protein_question_amount_1"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["protein_question_amount_2"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["protein_question_units_of_measurement"]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["protein_question_typing_method"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    ["protein_question_amount_1"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["protein_question_amount_2"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["protein_question_units_of_measurement"]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
  ["distributionId"]=>
  string(2) "21"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a very basic implementation to get you started, you may want to adjust it to your specific needs:

```php
<?php

$values = [
        'protein_question_0_typing_method' => '38',
        'protein_question_0_amount_1' => '1',
        'protein_question_0_amount_2' => '2',
        'protein_question_0_units_of_measurement' => '17',
        'protein_question_1_typing_method' => '39',
        'protein_question_1_amount_1' => '2',
        'protein_question_1_amount_2' => '2',
        'protein_question_1_units_of_measurement' => '17',
        'protein_question_2_typing_method' => '42',
        'protein_question_2_amount_1' => '2',
        'protein_question_2_amount_2' => '2',
        'protein_question_2_units_of_measurement' => '17',
        'distributionId' => '21'
];

function convert($values) {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $matches = [];
        $ret = preg_match('~^protein_question_([0-9]+)_~U', $key, $matches);

        // Key does not match the pattern protein_question_*_
        if ($ret !== 1) {
            $result[$key] = $value;

            continue;
        }

        $proteinQuestionID = (int)$matches[1];

        // Create key for the this ID
        if (!isset($result[$proteinQuestionID])) {
            $result[$proteinQuestionID] = [];
        }

        // Adjust the key...
        $key = \substr($key, \strlen('protein_question_'.$proteinQuestionID));
        $key = 'protein_question'.$key;

        // Append to it...
        $result[$proteinQuestionID][$key] = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(convert($values));
```

Answer (score -2):

did you tried array_chunk($your_array, 4) . it looks this method can help you

Comment: That won't give me the keys that I need

Comment: this will create a numeric-indexed array for you. take a look at second parameter, it is the number of elements you want to be in your arrays

Comment: yeah but I need the keys within the numerically indexed array, otherwise how will I know which fields to pull out?I have to use numerical indexes.